# What's the difference between the Nintendo Switch and the Nintendo Switch Lite?

Tags: nintendo-switch, nintendo-switch-lite

The only difference that I know is that the Nintendo Switch Lite (NSL) doesn't come with a AC adapter, and an HDMI cable for your TV. And the NS (Nintendo Switch) does. I also know that you can take off the sides on the NS and use it as a controller. But, I don't know any other differences apart from the ones that I stated. I will be using this information to figure out which one I'll be buying.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

According to the [Nintendo website](https://www.nintendo.com/switch/compare/), here are the differences between systems:

- Switch Lite is **handheld only** and cannot be used with a TV or monitor display.
- Switch Lite **can only play specific Switch games**, while the Switch can play all. The compatibility of the Switch lite is essentially down to whether or not the game can be played in handheld mode. You can check this by looking at the back of the game box (or checking the game's eShop page) for handheld compatibility.
- The results vary depending on model, but the **newer Switch models last around 1.5 - 2 hours longer**.
- The Lite **doesn't include a camera** (note that by this I mean the Switch's infrared camera and the HD camera).
- The Lite has a **smaller screen** of 5.5", while the standard switch has a screen of 6.2"
- The Switch is $299.99 while the Lite version is $199.99.

*There are a few other differences*, such as processing units and color options, but these are the most important differences. In truth, I would recommend the standard Switch, as it has more customization options and is much more like a console than the Lite version, which is basically a modernized DS Lite.

Answer (score 5):

The Nintendo Switch has a few extra features above the lite, for +100 dollar cost.
I'll list a few:

- Dock compatibility (the lite won't fit)
- Ability to send display to TV (using the dock, which the Lite doesn't support)
- Detachable JoyCons (the controllers)
- Longer battery life (speculation, I think I heard it from somewhere)

All in all, I would get the normal Switch and not the Lite.

Comment: Longer battery life depends on the switch version, not on normal vs lite.

Comment: Unless I was in a hurry,I wouldn’t buy either model right now. I’d wait and see what the rumoured Switch Pro looks like if and when it is formally announced.